# Find a group of unreachable nodes (from each other)

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Let there be a directed Graph G.

U is a set of 'black' vertices in G Such That:

1. Every element of G\U (whites) has a path to a black vertice.
2. There is no path between any elements of U( black).

Give me an algorithm searches for the group U in this graph.

Official Solution from my proffesor:

- Use kosaraju's algorithm for Strongly Connected Components.
- Find the graph of Strongly connected components.
- Every subgraph is a node in GSCC, for every subgraph in GSCC that has outdegree 0, mark one of the nodes inside the subgraph as black.

Comment: Why do call U nodes unreachable?  Maybe "unreachable form each other"

Comment: Say G is a cycle (e.g. a->b->c->a). Would you say that any one node could be black and satisfy the condition, or does a black node having a path back to itself (but no other black node) violate condition 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a black vertex is not allowed a path back to itself then some graphs will have no solution. E.g., any graph which is a cycle. For this reason, I'm assuming you allow black nodes to have paths to themselves, but to no other black node.

1. Begin by adding all vertices with outdegree zero to U.
2. Run BFS backwards from the vertices of U, and let X be the set of vertices BFS never reaches.
3. If X is empty then you're done, otherwise repeatedly do the following:
4. Pick any vertex in X. Run BFS forwards from it until you reach any vertex for the second time. Remove this vertex from X and color it black (add it to U). Now, run BFS backwards from this vertex, and remove all vertices you reach from X. Repeat all of (4) if X is nonempty.

Comment: Could you explain why having out degree 0 is not enough? More importantly, what do you mean BFS backwards from U? For every vertice of U do BFS?

Comment: @NatiShen-Gordon Well, say you have a graph with three vertices: {a, b, c}, and three arcs: (a, b), (b, c), (c, a). In short, the graph is a small cycle. In this case, there are no vertices of outdegree zero, but making any one vertex black lets all white vertices reach a black vertex, but no black vertex reach a different black vertex. Is this your intent, or would you say in this example there is no solution?

Comment: A black node can have a path to itself. The solution will be running BFS as many times as there are black nodes?

Comment: @NatiShen-Gordon No. The BFS in step 2 is from the set U. This is identical to running BFS to a node adjacent to exactly U. After that, you may run BFS repeatedly in 4, but the work is limited because we remove everything we reach (from X).

Comment: If I meet a vertex for the 2nd time doesn't it mean there's a cycle and it should be black?,

Comment: @NatiShen-Gordon That's how step 4 works. We find a vertex on a cycle, remove it, and remove anything that leads into it. The reason we don't just pick an arbitrary vertex from X is that X could include vertices that lead into cycles but don't belong to them. E.g.,  a->b->c->d->b. We shouldn't pick the vertex a here, but any of b, c, d would  be fine.

Comment: @NatiShen-Gordon Oh, I see. I forgot to state "paint in black and add it to U" in step four. That's exactly right, and I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I think this answer is very good.
I will update once I have the official answer off of my proffessorr

Answer (score 1):

"Vertices with out degree 0" is a necessary condition for a black vertex, but not sufficient.  They also MUST have at least one in link from a white vertex.

So the algorithm to find the black vertices:

- LOOP over vertices

  - IF out degree == 0
    Add to list of candidate blacks
  - ELSE
    Add to list of whites
- set finished false
- WHILE finished == false

  - set finished true
  - LOOP b over candidate blacks

    - set blackOK false
    - LOOP w over whites

      - IF link between b, w

        - set blackOK true
        - BREAK from loop w
    - IF blackOK false

      - move b from black to white list
      - set finished false
      - CONTINUE loop b

Comment: If they have out degree 0 how would they be linked to other black vertices? Also, how would we determine if a white node is connected?

Comment: You are correct.  Edited my answer.

Comment: I've edited my question it was not very clear I'd be happy id you took a look

Comment: Please edit the last line in your question.  I suggest deleting it entirely.

Comment: "They also MUST have at least one in link from a white vertex." -- Why? OP says every white vertex has a path to a black vertex, not that every black vertex has a path from a white vertex. E.g., if the graph has 1 vertex, I think coloring that black is a valid solution.

Comment: "Vertices with out degree 0" is a necessary condition for a black vertex. Why? Say our graph is (a,b), (b,c), and (c,a). Then any one node can be black and satisfy the conditions. Well, or not, depends whether the OP allows paths back to the same node or not.

Comment: I'd be happy if you took a look, I've updated the official solution of my proffessor. very nice question.